# Who gets a "patent grant cover" from the USPTO?

Tags: usa, documents

The [USPTO has designed a new "patent grant cover"](https://www.uspto.gov/about-us/news-updates/uspto-unveils-new-patent-cover-design-south-southwest-sxsw) in 2018:

> The patent grant cover represents the physical document issued to inventors upon the granting of a U.S. patent. The 225-plus year history of the patent cover has seen fewer than a dozen basic designs since President George Washington granted the first patent in 1790. Previous designs featured calligraphy, elaborate engravings, and high-quality typesetting.
>
> The patent office has only redesigned the document twice in the last hundred years, and the current design is more than 30 years old. A team of in-house USPTO graphic designers created the new patent cover design. After several iterations, Commissioner for Patents Drew Hirshfeld made the final selection.

This is a surprise to me -- I am an inventor on a number of issued U.S. patents and I have never received such a document. (There is a cottage industry of companies from which you can purchase plaques displaying an issued patent, but these aren't any sort of official document.)

Who gets them? Do they get sent to the assignee?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they get sent to the assignee.  It is just a card stock cover stapled to the same patent you can print out online. It does have a cool ribbon glued to it and is sometimes called the "ribboned copy". These things used to be like a deed and were kept in corporate safes but are now a relic without any power. Some countries have done away with them while others (China) still have elaborate colored and ribboned covers.