# Recordation of Patent Grant

Tags: uspto, patent-services, documents

This question is related to

[Who gets a "patent grant cover" from the USPTO?](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/who-gets-a-patent-grant-cover-from-the-uspto)

Does the "ribboned copy" get sent to overseas inventor/assignee (at recorded overseas address) by USPTO if such person gets a 'patent grant' for a patent application persued pro se at USPTO ?

Comment: When contacted, Application Assistance Unit (AAU) of USPTO replied that it has been mailed through US mail to India on October 09, 2018. I am yet to receive the same.